# Specify NLS-Settings during Oracle installation under Windows

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, oracle-12c, nls

Is there an easy way to specify NLS parameters for the database during the installation?

We want to install a new database (environment: Windows). For testing purpose we need NLS settings for nls_language and nls_territory that differ from the default values (German instead of American). To avoid the process of dropping an recreating the database with changed init.ora I would like to specify those setting during a fresh installation on a VM.

I found no settings in the setup dialogue. Is there any way to achieve this?

environment: Oracle Database Enterprise Edition, available versions 11.2 or 12.1.

Answer (score 1):

From the Oracle forums:  https://community.oracle.com/thread/777001

It appears that `NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS` is essentially a permanent copy of the values in `NLS_INSTANCE_PARAMETERS` at the time of database creation and cannot be changed later.  Reasoning given in link above is that `NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS` is used by the data dictionary to validate `CHECK` constraints and changing these parameters could violate those constraints.

`NLS_LANGUAGE` and `NLS_TERRITORY` need to be set to the desired values in your parameter file at the time the `CREATE DATABASE` statement is issued for the values to be stored in `NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do simply like

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET NLS_LANGUAGE='ENGLISH' SCOPE=SPFILE;
ALTER SYSTEM SET NLS_TERRITORY='GERMANY' SCOPE=SPFILE;
```

Another way would be to change your `NLS_LANG` environment variable in Windows (or Registry, but I don't know which one takes precedence) and restart the DB.

See [NLS_LANGUAGE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/initparams151.htm#REFRN10123) and [NLS_TERRITORY](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/initparams156.htm#REFRN10128)

Comment: Yes and no. `ALTER SYSTEM` changes the NLS-settings for the instance_parameters.

So `SELECT * FROM nls_instance_parameters;` shows that those changes are in effect, but `SELECT * FROM nls_database_parameters;` stays unchanged.

I got a weird application which relies on those database settings, at least their support-agents state that it does.

Any ideas except the long way of dropping and recreating the database?

To the registry: `NLS_LANG` is set to `GERMAN_GERMANY.WE8MSWIN1252`, cause we used a german windows for testing. But nls_database_parameters default to `NLS_LANGUAGE=AMERICAN etc.`

Comment: Strange, you can set `NLS_LANGUAGE` and `NLS_TERRITORY` individually on session base. Maybe you can force it with a `AFTER LOGON TRIGGER`

Comment: Indeed, I fear this 3rd party software relies on a direct `SELECT FROM nls_database_parameters`, I'll consult their support and try to get some clarification. And will try the LOGON TRIGGER while I wait for their response. ;-) Thank you!